# Laravel Eloquent, How to define tables relation with formula?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

On Laravel Eloquent,

How can I define relation condition with something that not exist on the table but calculated from a value in the table.

For example :

```
quarters                transactions
 _________ _________    _________ ___________
|   name  |  desc   |  |   id  |  date        |
 _________ _________    _________ ___________
|     1   | Jan-Mar |  |     1   | 2016-04-01 |
|     2   | Apr-Jun |  |     2   | 2016-05-01 |
|     3   | Jul-Sep |  |     3   | 2012-07-21 |
|     4   | Oct-Dec |  |     4   | 2014-01-31 |
 _________ _________    _________ ___________
```

It's work fine with this

```
SELECT 
FROM transactions tx
INNER JOIN quarters q ON q.name = ((MONTH(tx.date)+2)/3)
```

Quarters.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Quarters extends Model{

}
```

Transactions.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Transactions extends Model{

    public function quater(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Quarters' , '????', 'name') ;
    }
}
```

What should I define in my model in order to be able to do:

`Transactions::where("some_field", "some_value")->with("quater")->get()`

**note**: I want to do this without modify table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up created my own Relation class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use App\Models\Quarter;

class HasManyQuarter extends HasMany {

    public function __construct($localKey, $object){
        $instance = new Quarter;
        $query = $instance->newQuery();
        $foreign_key = "name";

        parent::__construct($query, $object, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreign_key, $localKey);
    }

    public function addEagerConstraints(array $models)
    {
        $keys = $this->getKeys($models, $this->localKey);
        $_keys = array();
        foreach($keys as $idx => $k){
            $_keys[$idx] = ( date("n", strtotime($k))+2 ) / 3; // Transform the Key
        }

        $this->query->whereIn($this->foreignKey, $keys);
    }

    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {
        $dictionary = $this->buildDictionary($results);

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $key = $model->getAttribute($this->localKey);

            $month = ( date("n", strtotime($key))+2 ) / 3; // Transform the Key

            if ( isset($dictionary[ $month ]) ) {
                $value = $this->getRelationValue($dictionary, $month, 'many');
                $model->setRelation($relation, $value);
            }

        }
        return $models;
    }
}
```

And my model have:

```
public function quarter(){
   return new HasManyQuarter('date', $this);
}
```

I extends HasMany because it's suite my case where my real class are not transaction/quarter. but this can get anyone idea of how to implement it.

The idea is overide `addEagerConstraints` to alter the query and also `match()` to match the results back to each records.

[Relations/HasMany.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php)

Answer (score 1):

In order to do `Eloquent Relationship` you need another column in `Transection` table. Example:

```
      quarters                    transactions
 _________ _________    _________ ___________  ____________
|   name  |  desc   |  |   id    | quarter_id |    date    |
 _________ _________    _________ ___________  ____________
|     1   | Jan-Mar |  |     1   |      2     | 2016-04-01 |
|     2   | Apr-Jun |  |     2   |      2     | 2016-05-01 |
|     3   | Jul-Sep |  |     3   |      3     | 2012-07-21 |
|     4   | Oct-Dec |  |     4   |      1     | 2014-01-31 |
 _________ _________    _________ ___________ ______________
```

In this schema `quarter_id` is the catch for table `quarter_table`. Now you can define eloquent relationship in model like this:

**Transactions.php**

```
public function quarter(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Quarters') ;
}
```

**Quarters.php**

```
public function transactions(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Transactions') ;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$transactions = Transactions::where('quarter_id', $someValue)->get()

or

$transactions = Transactions::with('quarter')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. anyway, In my case,I cannot modify database structure. Do you have any other way around?

Comment: To make one-to-many eloquent relationship you will need a column for foreign key.